# Какова задача role="presentation"?

Tags: семантика, role, html5

Привет.

В каких случаях и для каких тегов применяется **role="presentation"**?

Если я правильно понял, он используется для блока, который не будет проиндексирован.
Это обычно вспомогательные элементы для корректной разметны, не имеющих ценной инфы.
Любые атрибуты rol внутри него будуть проигнорированы.

Comment: При чем тут индексация, это просто роль интерфейса, который, типа, может быть подхвачен операционной системой. Ну, там кнопки, меню, списки и прочая морковина. Индексировать там нечего, как правило, поскольку нет статистически устойчивых связей со текстом, с его смыслом.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation

Answer (score 1):

Знаете такие программы, типа NVDA screen reader, freedom scientific jaws, Apple VoiceOver, etc...
Так вот знайте, что все эти роли предназначены в основном именно для таких программ. Чтобы они могли корректно читать и поддерживать интерфейсы. А на визуальную часть (которую мы смотрим как обычно, глазами, без программ) она не меняется от ролей.